# How to apply the degree of truthfulness in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

It displays several diseases. I want only the nearest diseases to be retrieve in the database base on what I've input. Then, the result is **LUPUS AND MEASLES**

```
<?php

    include('connect.php');

        //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection

        //Sanitize the POST values


            $symptom1 = $_POST['symptom1'];
            $symptom2 = $_POST['symptom2'];
            $symptom3 = $_POST['symptom3'];
            $symptom4 = $_POST['symptom4'];

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT disease FROM diseases WHERE 
            symptom1 LIKE '%". $symptom1."%' OR symptom1 LIKE '%". $symptom2."%' OR symptom1 LIKE '%". $symptom3."%' OR symptom1 LIKE '%". $symptom4."%' AND
            symptom2 LIKE '%". $symptom1."%' OR symptom2 LIKE '%". $symptom2."%' OR symptom2 LIKE '%". $symptom3."%' OR symptom2 LIKE '%". $symptom4."%' AND
            symptom3 LIKE '%". $symptom1."%' OR symptom3 LIKE '%". $symptom2."%' OR symptom3 LIKE '%". $symptom3."%' OR symptom3 LIKE '%". $symptom4."%' AND
            symptom4 LIKE '%". $symptom1."%' OR symptom4 LIKE '%". $symptom2."%' OR symptom4 LIKE '%". $symptom3."%' OR symptom4 LIKE '%". $symptom4."%'");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {   
                    echo $row['disease'];
            }   
            //end of while loop

?>
```

[query code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fBSk.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z59d3.png)

Comment: what does "nearest" mean? Number of symptom matches or something else?

Comment: @mseifert here is the scenario, I've input 4 symptoms: 1=fever,2=headache, 3=fatigue and 4=swollen joints. the result is lupus and measles. I want only lupus because it has all of the 4 input symptoms while the measles has got only 1 and that is the fever symptom.

Comment: @jankryss - Why are you using `LIKE`?  Do the input symptoms not match the DB symptoms exactly?

Comment: they do match, i just did the multidimentional reading of data @StevenMoseley

Comment: @jankryss - More concerns about the above.  You want `mysql_fetch_assoc` (not array).  `mysql_query` is deprecated (use `mysqli_query` instead).  You have no `die()` clause for query errors.  You have no sql-injection protection on your $_POST params.

Comment: I think you should redo your table structure. What if a disease has 5 or more symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Seems what you actually want is a fulltext index:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ix_disease_symptoms 
ON diseases(symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4);
```

Then query it using MATCH:

```
$symptom1 = $_POST['symptom1'];
$symptom2 = $_POST['symptom2'];
$symptom3 = $_POST['symptom3'];
$symptom4 = $_POST['symptom4'];

$sql = "SELECT disease,
            MATCH(symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4) 
            AGAINST('{$symptom1} {$symptom2} {$symptom3} {$symptom4}') AS score
        FROM diseases 
        WHERE MATCH(symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4) 
            AGAINST('{$symptom1} {$symptom2} {$symptom3} {$symptom4}')
        ORDER BY score DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
        echo $row['disease'];
    }
} else {
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: if I put parenthesis then I'm unable to get other diseases, it will end up retrieving only the disease that has 4 symptoms matched into the database

Comment: I see... you seem to want a fulltext index

Comment: CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ix_disease_symptoms 
ON diseases(symptom1, symptom2, symptom3, symptom4);

sir, I will create another table for this ? then insert my symptoms data?

Comment: No, you'll create an index on your existing table, which will make the columns searchable using fulltext queries.

Comment: ok I did it already but. there in an error to the query that you gave sir.

Comment: its posted as image under the topic sir.

Comment: To print errors propery, you need to "die": `if ($sql) {  /* do your mysql_fetch_array() code */ } else { die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()); }`

Comment: Added `die()` syntax in my answer.  Update your code and run again to see the SQL error.

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\skinAid\howtouse.php on line 56 `code`
thats the new error sir

Comment: Well yeah, because I forgot to update $sql to $result in that function call.

Comment: it is already displaying a result sir, I already input 3 symptoms matched then 1st disease to be displayed was the disease with 3 inputs matched in the database the rest is just 2 below symptoms matched. I just need now to get the 1st line of the display.

Comment: Did you update $sql to $result in mysql_fetch_assoc as I did in my answer above?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="
    SELECT 
      disease,
      (
        symptom1 LIKE '%" . $symptom1 . "%' 
        OR symptom1 LIKE '%" . $symptom2 . "%' 
        OR symptom1 LIKE '%" . $symptom3 . "%' 
        OR symptom1 LIKE '%" . $symptom4 . "%'
      ) + (
        symptom2 LIKE '%" . $symptom1 . "%' 
        OR symptom2 LIKE '%" . $symptom2 . "%' 
        OR symptom2 LIKE '%" . $symptom3 . "%' 
        OR symptom2 LIKE '%" . $symptom4 . "%'
      ) + (
        symptom3 LIKE '%" . $symptom1 . "%' 
        OR symptom3 LIKE '%" . $symptom2 . "%' 
        OR symptom3 LIKE '%" . $symptom3 . "%' 
        OR symptom3 LIKE '%" . $symptom4 . "%'
      ) + (
        symptom4 LIKE '%" . $symptom1 . "%' 
        OR symptom4 LIKE '%" . $symptom2 . "%' 
        OR symptom4 LIKE '%" . $symptom3 . "%' 
        OR symptom4 LIKE '%" . $symptom4 . "%'
      ) AS `score` 
    FROM
      diseases 
    HAVING `score` > 0 
    ORDER BY `score` DESC";
```

Comment: I tried it but no disease was retrieved even if I input 3 of the matching symptoms in the database

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic argument for the importance of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Consider a redesign of your relational table schema with:

1. a distinct **Diseases** table
2. a distinct **Symptoms** table
3. a **DisesaseSymptomsJoin** table as a many-to-many join with Diseases and Symptoms where multiple diseases can maintain multiple symptoms shared among each other.

Additionally, there is no need for complex, composite, or full text keys. Plus, this structure scales well with infinite amount of Diseases and Symptoms instead of limited to 4 each.

[image: Table Normalization]

Most importantly, queries are much simpler to read and maintain where no longer do you need to check all ordinal possibilities of four `Symptom` combinations given a user's selection but a simple, clear `IN`or `OR` clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT d.Disease, 
               ds.SymptomID, 
               s.Symptom
        FROM Diseases d
        INNER JOIN DiseaseSymptomJoin ds
                ON d.DiseaseID = ds.DiseaseID 
        INNER JOIN Symptoms s
                ON ds.SymptomID = s.SymptomID
        WHERE s.Symptom 
                IN (".$symptom1.", ".$symptom2.", ".$symptom3.", ".$symptom4.")";
```

Alternatively, with aggregation for scores:

```
 $sql = "SELECT Disease, 
                Score
         FROM
               (SELECT d.DiseaseID, 
                       d.Disease,
                       Count(*) As score
                FROM Diseases d
                INNER JOIN DiseaseSymptomJoin ds
                        ON d.DiseaseID = ds.DiseaseID 
                INNER JOIN Symptoms s
                        ON ds.SymptomID = s.SymptomID
                WHERE s.Symptom 
                    IN (".$symptom1.", ".$symptom2.", ".$symptom3.", ".$symptom4.")
                GROUP BY d.DiseaseID,
                         d.Disease
         ) As dT
         ORDER BY score DESC";
```